# Node.js Syntax Error "unexpected Token"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a game website for my own self study and the only problem I got now is that when I try to run the code the only problem i get is with this part,

```
socket.on('showmssages',function(data)
{
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE `steamid`="'+data+'"', function(err, rows, fields)
});
```

The end part **});** where **}** exist it says *SyntaxError: Unexpected token*.

What am I doing wrong? Got any Idea?

Comment: Your function is incomplete...

Comment: You're missing the `)` from the `connection.query()` call.

Comment: You should provide the callback function implementation for `connection.query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
socket.on('showmssages',function(data){
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE 
    `steamid`="'+data+'"', 
    function(err, rows, fields){
       //your function stuff
    })//function and connection.query closed
});//socket.on closed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the block for the callback function in connection.query() and its closing parenthesis.

```
connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE `steamid`="'+data+'"', function(err, rows, fields) {
  // you should be doing stuff here with the data returned from query
});
```